# Binding WPF ListBox entirely from Codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I want to bind a common WPF Listbox with different types of List at different occassion.

How to do it entirely from C# code behind file only.

Here I declared it in XAML

```
 <ListBox MaxHeight="190" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
 x:Name="myListBox"   SelectionChanged="OnItemSelected">
   </ListBox>
```

DataBinding through {Binding Path="PropertyName"} can be easily done on XAMl but since I am creating a user control to I will get a unique custom collection , SO I need to bind it from cs file only..

From C# code I am trying this way.

where EventLevels is a List and TelematicsEventLevel is a string..

```
myListBox.ItemsSource = EventLevels;
myListBox.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, "TelematicsEventLevel");
```

Also tried this

```
public IEnumerable  ListSource { get;set; } //setting from parent control
public string PropertyName { get;set; } //setting it from parent control


myListBox.DisplayMemberPath = PropertyName; //assigning in child control itself
myListBox.ItemsSource = ListSource;//assigning in child control itself
```

Comment: Data Binding Overview - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx - Datacontext property

Comment: myListBox.SetBinding(property, path);

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863(v=vs.110).aspx (How to: Create binding in code)